# Python Yahoo Finance - data scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i'm new to programming and i'm just trying to get "Target price: value from yahoo finance
i tried beautifulsoup, xpath...but never succeed to extract the data
(241.21 $ ) on the following example

example : https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/analysis?p=MSFT

[Target price area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L93H7.png)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
ticker = 'MSFT'
url ='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+Symbol
page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(page.text, "html.parser")
for row in table:
    col = row.find_all('span')
    for c in col:
        print(c.text)
```

When printing all spans, it doesnt show up...

Comment: People are less likely to downvote you if you upload code

Comment: this could be a hint ```<div class="Pos(r) T(5px) Miw(100px) Fz(s) Fw(500) D(ib) C($primaryColor)Ta(c) Translate3d($half3dTranslate)"><span>Average</span><!-- react-text: 23 -->&nbsp;<!-- /react-text --><span>241.21</span></div>```

Comment: it also helps if the code works, what is "tables"?

Comment: Unfortunately it looks the the data you want to scrap is filled in by javascript. Therefore, the data does not exist when you use request to get the page. Javascript needs a browser to run on. Two options I see to scrap this is data is to 1) manually load the page in your browser, downloaded it, and scrap it from the downloaded page or 2) use Selenium to load the page and then scrap it.

Comment: You can also try "dryscrape"

Answer (score 0):

I've developed the following example to scrape the data you are interested in. This data was particularly difficult to get as it was filled in by javascript only once the page has scrolled down enough.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/analysis?p=MSFT')

# Scroll down to the container of the data. The Analyst Price Targets div.
# The needed data is not filled in until scrolled down
driver.execute_script("""document.querySelector('div#Aside div[data-reactid="48"]').scrollIntoView();""")

# Get the span that contains the data
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-test='analyst-avg-tg']//span[2]")
print(elem.text)
```